# Pentaho removed SolutionRepositoryService services?

Tags: java, web-services, pentaho, business-intelligence

I'm updating my Java client code from Pentaho BA v3.7 to 5.1.

Many things are still working, except that my code can't find the [SolutionRepositoryService services](http://infocenter.pentaho.com/help48/index.jsp?topic=%2Fintegrating_biserver%2Fconcept_understanding_solutionrepositoryservice.html).

The URL http:// localhost:8080/pentaho/SolutionRepositoryService?component=XXX is not working on the new version.

What is the URL for these services? Do I have to install anything else?

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they changed in v5.0 their whole API, and now they use a REST API.
Here is de descriptor file:

http://javadoc.pentaho.com/bi-platform500/webservice500/application.wadl

Import it to SoapUI and you're good to go to test the services.